# Weird behavior when compiling c# project after signing it

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I have this scenario:
In a very large solution on Visual Studio I have many projects, for different purpouse. Some of them are SharePoint Web Parts, others are WCF. And "Common" projects, which are used by the Web Parts and the WCF projects.
The problem starts when referencing the Commont Project to SharePoint Web Part because that project request me to sign all the projects that is referencing this project.

So after doing this, each time WCF is compiled, the referenced dll are not genereated to the bin directory. So the WCF dll not working as it might supposed to work.

I don't have any idea of what is wrong with the settings of any of the projects. So I don't know also if I need to provide any code to help me solving this weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the "Main" project, expand the references section and ensure that the other applications have the following setting in the properties window:

```
Copy Local - True
```

It sounds like the application is not copying the dll's because this setting may be false for each of your dependent projects.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify this, All the dlls have this property set to True

Comment: Interesting, well that's all I could think off. Can you manually build each one and copy the dll's? i know that is a hack, but i am curious if it works.And i am also assuming you have tried to "Clean" the solution and "Rebuild All". Sorry

Comment: Of course, I cleaned the solution and then re-built it. But whta I noticed is that the changes I've made actually doesn't appears on the wcf after  even if I compile each project and copy the dll to the wcf bin directory